# Getting "quotaExceeded" error after loading a query job

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting the following error after loading query jobs:

```
Reason: quotaExceeded
Location: load_job_per_table.long
Message: Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for imports or query appends per table. For more information, 
see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors
```

I am not sure which quota was exceeded. Is it:

1) The amount of jobs I can submit OR
2) The amount of rows I can append to the destination table from execution of the query

I can't find a more detailed explanation anywhere. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It says 'your table exceeded quota', run fewer inserts on that table.

Comment: Each query job appends more data to the destination table and I can't predict how many new rows will be appended. It seems to me it is the number of job "waiting" to be run that is the quote I am hitting. I can always still submit more jobs after I hit the error without waiting too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery has a limit for the number of batch modifications you can make to a particular table to 1000 per day. This is for two reasons: the first is that frequent small appends can cause the underlying representation of the table to be inefficient to query and to manage. The second reason is that you may be better off using the streaming api, which lets you append small amounts to your tables, up to 100,000 times per second.

Comment: I am not sure if that is what is happening. I would run into the quota error after submitting 500 query jobs. Wait a little bit, I would then be able to submit more query jobs and they would run just fine. That leads me to believe it is not a daily quota I am hitting. Maybe it is the number of query jobs I can have waiting to get run?

Comment: BigQuery daily quotas get refunded periodically in small increments. This prevents people from running into the daily quota and then being stuck.

Comment: Is there any way to increase that quota? Streaming inserts will be too costly for us since every query job results in millions of rows appended. Thanks.

Comment: If each of the inserts is adding a lot of data, we're generally happy to increase your quotas. Do you have a cloud support contact? If you e-mail them the details, we can raise your quota. Note, another option may be to do your loads to multiple tables and combine them in the query (as in SELECT foo from table1, table2, table3,...) or via a table copy operation.

Comment: No, I don't have a contact. It seems to me we must pay for at least Silver support in order to get one?

Comment: Please email me (tigani@google.com) with your project information, a justification for a quota boost, and the amount of quota that you'd like.

Comment: Since the Python streaming library was broken I used the load API and hit this limit during a batch import. Now I'll modify it to accumulate records before committing the packets to BigQuery. I think this limit is a sensible one.